# Install cx_Oracle in python3 with no oracle installed

Tags: windows, oracle, python-3.x, cx-oracle

I dont have Oracle installed at workstation. But I need to work with remote Oracle database by using Python3.

Is there any way I can install cx_Oracle in Python3 without having oracle installed on same workstation.

I am using Windows 8 with Python3 32-bit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Installing cx_oracle

Go to oracle and download these two .rpm packages and install them

```
http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/instantclient/11204/oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm?AuthParam=1478000633_68b649d2c439341db56788b83f6400e2

http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/instantclient/11204/oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm?AuthParam=1478000602_3699580c200cad38c6933ed4900b1c39
```

Run these commands one by one in your terminal

```
yum -y install libaio bc flex
rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm
echo 'export ORACLE_VERSION="11.2"' >> $HOME/.bashrc
echo 'export ORACLE_HOME="/usr/lib/oracle/$ORACLE_VERSION/client64/"' >> $HOME/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:"$ORACLE_HOME/bin"' >> $HOME/.bashrc
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:"$ORACLE_HOME/lib"' >> $HOME/.bashrc
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

Then you can install cx_Oracle with pip.

```
pip3 install cx_Oracle
```

and you can verify your installation with

```
pip3 list
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have an Oracle client installed. Fortunately, there is a simple Oracle instant client available which is easy to install (just unzip some files) and doesn't take up much space, either. Go here and follow the instructions on the page for your platform:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index.html